# can't connect to MySql database with Rmysql

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to connect to MySql database using RMysql (R version 3.3.1.). My code is:

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='odvjet12_mislav', password='xxxxx', host='odvjetnistvo-sagovac.hr')
```

I think I am entering wrong parameters:

user - is it a user that is specified as "Current user" in c panel or user that is specified when giving privileges to some user(example odvjet12_mislav)

pass - pass of the "Current user" or added user

host - I am not sure what should I type here: "Primary domain", "Shared IP Address" in Cpanel or something else?

Comment: User name and password are from the user you have granted access to in Mysql. Host is local host if Mysql is on the local machine otherwise url to access Mysql, like aws rds

Comment: I have tried all combinations, but without success. I always get the error `Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on`

Comment: I have a running app using RMysql and a MySQL database on Amazon RDS, have you granted access to a user in the database, what host parameter are you using?

Comment: You can try to dump the database from cpanel and run it locally